# Django app search not pulling data in Heroku but works locally?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

My django app locally works fine, I have a postgres DB and when I run a search it pulls data. I have pushed my DB to Heroku, the data is there, but when I run a search it says 'no results found'. I do not get how data is there and works locally but will not show results in Heroku, any ideas?

I am not sure what anyone would need to look at here but here is the logs after running a search. Let me know what else would be helpful
[image]

Comment: I haven't used Heroku for deployment, but something you might try is running a django shell in Heroku and manually performing some queries. Try to determine if your data is actually there and you are able to access it. That might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: How did you "push your db to Heroku"? How did you verify that the data is there?

Comment: Since I am on windows I had to do this crazy work around to push the data, First I had to dump my local database out to a dump file then pushed the dump file over, support needed to help me with this, said it is a bug with Heroku and windows machines. But I did run queries on the heroku DB and data shows: fast-wave-34782::DATABASE=> select supplier_code from products_supplierpart where supplier_code = 'BL18588';
 supplier_code 
---------------
 BL18588
(1 row)

Comment: Also general info shows 15 tables 121 rows Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version:  9.5.3
Created:     2016-05-26 01:55 UTC
Data Size:   8.2 MB
Tables:      15
Rows:        121/10000 (In compliance)

Comment: Heroku support said sometimes if local app is in development mode may act differently then in production mode which is how it is on Heroku...does this make any sense to anyone? I am not sure what they mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue is Whoosh does not work on Heroku because there is not a permanent disk to write to, guess I will be switching to Elastic Search...